# Speeding Up NIntegrate and ?NumericQ

Tags: numerical-integration

I have attached below a piece of code that has been running successfully but takes extremely long for mathematica to compute. I believe it is the last "rms" calculation and the fact that I am using very small numbers that is really pushing mathematica. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
c = 3*10^8;
e = 1.6*10^-19;
m = 9.1*10^-31;
rc = 2.8*10^-15;
gamma = 1600/0.511;
n = (10^-10)/e;
sbeg = 9.6*10^-5;
send = 1.1*10^-5;
lm = 0.5;
theta = 0.04;
r = lm/theta;


sL[phi_?NumericQ] := (r*phi^3)/24

lambda[z_, phi_] := n/(((send - sbeg)/theta phi + sbeg)*Sqrt[2 Pi])
   Exp[-(z^2/(2*((send - sbeg)/theta phi + sbeg)^2))]


de[s_, phi_?NumericQ] :=  With[{sL = sL[phi]}, 
(-((2*n*rc*m*c^2)/(3^(1/3) r^(2/3)))) 
*((lambda[s - sL, phi] - lambda[s - 4 sL, phi])/sL^(1/3) 
 + NIntegrate[(1/(s - sprime)^(1/3)*D[lambda[sprime, phi], sprime]),
       {sprime, s - sL,s}])]

total[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[de[s, phi], {phi, 0, theta}]

rms = Sqrt[
  NIntegrate[
    1/(sbeg*Sqrt[2 Pi])
      Exp[-(s^2/(2*(sbeg)^2))]*(total[s])^2, {s, -10 sbeg, 
     10 sbeg}] - (NIntegrate[
     1/(sbeg*Sqrt[2 Pi])
       Exp[-(s^2/(2*(sbeg)^2))]*(total[s]), {s, -10 sbeg, 
      10 sbeg}])^2]
```

Comment: The basic reason for the slowness is probably that you have  `NIntegrate` calls nested three deep.  Each `NIntegrate` might evaluate its integrand several hundred times, which means the interior integrands might be evaluated a million up to tens of millions of times.